# Neo4j post-order state

Tags: neo4j

I want to do something like this in Neo4j using the Java API (not a cypher query]. Say I have a graph which is a simple path looking like this:

[5]->[4]->[3]->[2]->[1]->[0]

and I want to output a String "012345" but starting the traversal from the node [5]. This means I need something like post-order traversal while keeping an intermediate string at each node. However, I do not want to create some kind of map from nodes to strings. Is such a thing possible with the traversal API of Neo4j? For example by using states?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse from the node[5] to get the path [5]->[0], and then use the function path.reverseNodes() to get the nodes on the path in reverse order.